# Add custom Form to Review and Payments page

Tags: magento2, custom, forms, checkout-page, addfield

There are many examples online about adding a custom form with custom fields to the shipping-step, but I would like to know how to add a custom form with fields to the billing-step page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same. You should take a look at the Sales rule module.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```